Plotting the Rappaport plot of area V.S. distance coverage with shadowing using matlab
I am trying to plot the Rappaport plot (area vs. distance coverage with shadowing) using MATLAB. The goal is to create a graph that resembles the one in the figure below:

I already tried doing so in matlab using the formulas given to me in class:
https://latex.codecogs.com/svg.image?&space;U(%5Cgamma)=%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B2%7D%5B1-erf(a)+e%5E%5Cfrac%7B1-2ab%7D%7Bb%5E2%7D%5B1-erf(%5Cfrac%7B1-ab%7D%7Bb%7D)%5D]
https://latex.codecogs.com/svg.image?a=%5Cfrac%7B%5Cgamma-P_t+%5Coverline%7BPL%7D(d_0)-10n&space;log(%5Cfrac%7BR%7D%7Bd_0%7D)}{\sigma\sqrt{2}}
https://latex.codecogs.com/svg.image?b=%5Cfrac%7B10n&space;log(e)%7D%7B%5Csigma%5Csqrt%7B2%7D}
Could anyone help me identify what might be going wrong in my code or suggest ways to improve the plot to match the expected output?
I have implemented the code below, which should calculate the function () for various gamma values and sigma/n ratios.
% Parameters
Pt = 30; % Transmitted power in dBm
PL_d0 = 60; % Path loss at reference distance (in dB)
sigma = 8; % Standard deviation of shadowing (in dB)
n = 3.5; % Path loss exponent
d0 = 1; % Reference distance (in meters)
R = 10; % Cell radius (in meters)
gamma_values = linspace(1, 0, 10); % Reverse gamma threshold values

% Define distance and sigma/n values
sigma_n_ratio = linspace(0, 8, 100); % Varying sigma/n (shadowing effect)
U = zeros(length(gamma_values), length(sigma_n_ratio));

% Compute U(gamma) for different values of gamma and sigma/n
for j = 1:length(gamma_values)
    gamma = gamma_values(j);
    for i = 1:length(sigma_n_ratio)
        sigma_n = sigma_n_ratio(i);
        a = (gamma - Pt + PL_d0 - 10*n*log10(R/d0)) / (sigma_n * sqrt(2));
        b = (10*n*log10(exp(1))) / (sigma_n * sqrt(2));
        % U(gamma) equation
        U(j, i) = 0.5 * (1 - erf(a) + exp((1 - 2*a*b) / b^2) * (1 - erf((1 - a*b) / b)));
    end
end

% Plotting
figure;
hold on;
for j = 1:length(gamma_values)
    plot(sigma_n_ratio, U(j, :), 'DisplayName', sprintf('Pr[r > %0.2f]', gamma_values(j)));
end
xlabel('\sigma/n');
ylabel('Fraction of total area with signal above threshold, U(\gamma)');
legend('show');
title('Plot of Area vs. Distance Coverage with Shadowing');
grid on;

However, the graph I am getting does not look as expected, as shown below:

The shape of the curves seems incorrect, and the values don't match the expected behavior. I suspect there may be an issue with how I'm applying the formulas or with how the parameters interact.

Background
For the wider audience, this question is about graph figure 3.18 page 108 of seminal literature reference
Mobile Communications Wireless Communications Principles and Practice
author T.Rappaport, ed Prentice Hall, 2nd ed.
This book like Bruce Carlson's Telecommunication Systems, and The Terminator, may be old, but not obsolete.
Back in the day, as shown in preceding graph 3.17

mobile operators had to sample received power by customer equipment, and then approximate the vast rest of points left behind with, not the ideal path loss (far too optimistic), but with a higher slope loss.
Slope n may be as high as 6.
Sought Graph
This question is about how to reproduce graph 3.18

showing Fraction of total (cell) area with (received) signal above threshold U over sigma/n.
U[W] and gamma received power by mobile phones.
sigma is noise deviation, an additional noise added as coverage modelling, besides the channel noise between tower and mobile phone.
n is the slope of the lines attempting to model a large enough amount of field measurements to achieve a certain percentage of confidence that enough mobile phones are going to hold wireless channels with BER above threshold to keep conversations and download/upload data.
This aditional noise is gaussian and deliverately further 'annoys' received power to model disparity of received power measurements obtained by the operator upon driving around and sampling Pr received power.
sigma^2 noise power of this additional noise to model the so called 'shadowing'.
PL path loss, Pr and gamma all powers in dBm(W) .
p(Pr(r)>gamma) means probability of received power Pr on any radial point at a distance r from cell tower enjoying received power above the threshold power gamma.
gamma[W] is the threshold received power below which mobile phones can no longer distiguish tower signals from noise and interference.
Generating U(gamma) Graphs
So, having clarified all the above, let's get to the point
The question starts with these parameters
close all;clear all;clc

sqrt2=sqrt(2);
e=exp(1);

Pt = 30;                                    % [dBm(W)] Transmitted power 
PLd0 = 60;                              % [dB] Path loss at reference distance R CELL BOUNDARY

d0 = 1000;                                 % [m] Reference distance 
R = 1000;                                   % [m] Cell radius
dr=1;
r=[0:dr:R];

correction : d0=1;R=10; or R=whatever is not correct.
One does not take right next to tower measurements as reference values.
On the contrary, one should go to worst spots where one expects to have low or no coverage, because 100% coverage is the target, or as close to 100% as possible.
It's is logic to presume that along cell edge r=R is lowest coverage happens.
May there is worse than edge coverage on other spots r<R.
But if one secures perimeter, then it's highly likely that there are going to be fewer poor coverage spots with r<R.
correction : the question originator used the expression of a with  +- error

Note that Pt-PL is Transmitter Power - Path Loss = Received Power, Pr.
gamma - Pr is the link budget margin above threshold gamma.
A large budget margin and BER is going to be outstanding, but such margin has to be adjusted as close as possible to threshold gamma, while staying above gamma, to optimize resources.
Following, the expression b

Following U(gamma) used by the question originator, that from a quick reading seems to be what it is used to generate graph 3.18

But not quite.
The expression that I think Rappaport's reference [Reu74] uses is preceeding (to 3.78) equation 3.77, the direct integral, not equation 3.78 .
The access to [Reu74] costs $33.- in the IEEE portal for non IEEE members.
A 1974 article and still with this price? There's been a surge in readings recently because omnidirerctional antennas are back on the field for newest standard 5G for specific scenarios.

Also equation 3.77 works well with high probabilty (close to 1) but it's equation 3.79 that better matches curves for low probability (close to 0.5).
n=3                % slope
s_ov_n=[0:.2:8];   % sigma/n

pr=[.5 .55 .6 .65 .7 .75 .8 .85 .9 .95];   % probability

% Pr(Pr(d)<gamma)=Q((Prd0-gamma)/sigma)
% Q(z)=.5*erfc(z/sqrt2)
% pr(Pr(d)<gamma)=.5*erfc((Prd0-gamma)/(sigma*sqrt2))
% erfcinv(2*pr(Pr(d)<gamma))=(Prd0-gamma)/(sigma*sqrt2)

% sigma_n_ratio = sigma./n;         % Varying sigma/n (shadowing effect)
% PL_=@(r) 10*n*log10(R/d0)+10*n*log10(r/R)+PLd0;

% PL=PLd0+10*n*log10(r/R)

% Pr=Pt-PL

% b = (10*n*log10(e))./(s*sqrt2);

% a=(g-Pt+10*n*log10(r/R))/(s*sqrt2)  % gamma - (Pt- PL(ommited)) is g minus Pr : Pr_min_gamma

% direct integration

U1=zeros(numel(pr),numel(s_ov_n));
str1={};

for k2=1:1:numel(pr)

for k1=1:1:numel(s_ov_n)
    
    Pr_min_gamma=sqrt2*n*s_ov_n(k1)*erfcinv(2*pr(k2)); 
  
    fun1=@(r) r.*erf(  (Pr_min_gamma+10*n.*log10(r/R))/(n*s_ov_n(k1)*sqrt2)  +   (10*n*log10(e))/(n*s_ov_n(k1)*sqrt2)  .* log(r/R));

    U1(k2,k1)=.5-1/R^2*integral(fun1,0,R);

end

str1{k2}=num2str(pr(k2));

end

figure(1)
for k2=1:1:numel(pr)
plot(s_ov_n,U1(k2,:))
hold on
end
grid on
legend(str1,'Location','northeastoutside')


Note that the way to go from received powers to confidence probabilty is through the statistical function Q, or equivalently with MATLAB command erfcinv . Find out how to invert Q with erfcinv reading qfunc help and erfcinv help
Using expressions a and b
a=(Pr_min_gamma  +10*n*log10(r/R))/(s*sqrt2);
b = (10*n*log10(e))./(s*sqrt2);

% U2=.5*(1-erf(a)+exp((1-2*a*b)/b^2)*(1-erf((1-a*b)/b))) 

a produces values for each r position and a as vector attemps operation on scalars : syntax error .
Applying d0=R
then a=0 and U expression simplfies to U(b)
U3=.5*(1+exp(1/b^2)*(1-erf(1/b))) 

For n=4;s=8;pr=.75 or n=2;s=8;pr=.75 this expression of U3 doesn't match graph 3.18 but it is exact for n=3;s=9;pr=.5

Comments
1.
For this particular modelling Rappaport points at these 2 references
[Jak74] Jr Microwave Mobile Communications
Wiley, 1974
Author : W.C. Jakes
[Reu74] Properties of Mobile Radio Propagation Above 400MHz
IEEE Transactions on Vehicular Technology, Vol23 n2 pp1-20 Nov 1974
DOI: 10.1109/T-VT.1974.23587  link
Author : D.O. Reudnick
2.
I guess there's an additional undisclosed approximation that may be
revealed in [Reu74], not in [Jak74] I checked, that uses the integral
form for high pr (pr close to 1) yet it uses U(b) for low pr (pr around .5)
3.
There are many deployed 5G antennas covering cell sectors.
Yet in the University of Surrey I saw omnidirectional antennas for 5G as well.
Using this annular coverage modelling may make sense for omnidirectional antennas.
But this Log-normal approximation, as mentioned in Rappaport's, for a circular 'shadowing' to model disparity of received power, may not be as accurate having the phones telling the base station what is the actual Pr each one has.
And they do it all the time.
I mention this because with current procesing power and the capacity to take many more measurements than back in 70's and 90's , yes good operators always do field validation measurements with service phones owned by the operator, but no, nowadays what is it that end customer devices do not reveal to the operator, if not the colour of the smartphone ?
By this I mean customer smart phones can and do relay back to tower in real time received power, along with location and a long long list of other things.
Such real time data collection is necessary to optimize wireless channels. It's not big brother stuff, it's the nature of robust wireless channels : If you want high BER both sides of each link have to talk, alot, all the time.
So, do you really need adding a gaussian stochastic variable to an n-slope ideal path loss to guess what power is being received out of a really small amount of field measurements? when you can directly ask each smartphone, all the time.
Hope it helps.
If you found this answer useful please conside marking it as accepted answer. Thanks.

Too much to say :)
It's only quite easy when one realizes that the value of "a" encompasses all unknowns that need to be determined. The parameter "b" is independent of these unknowns ... So U(gamma) is only a function of "a" and "b". The value of b varies as a function of sigma/n. Manually vary the values of the "a" parameter and you will have all of the distinct curves.
Good luck!
